# PHP If Statement Being Overridden

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm working on a search page and one of the bits of result information is location.  One of the things to search for is music albums (which doesn't have location information).

http://www.flcbranson.org/freedownloads-search.php

If you search for "rock", you'll see The Peace Of God - Pt. 3 - My Rock with location information (that's not the way it's supposed to be).  If you do a search for "my rock", you'll notice that there is no location information listed for that same record (the way it is supposed to be).  It's like the if statement is being overridden if another result does have location information.

The music albums have `$row["Number"]` of Music01, Music02, etc... and all other records should be null or a number (which should all be less than Musicxx.  As far as I can tell, this code should only display location information if it's not a music album.

```
<?php
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    if ($row["Number"] < "Music01") {
        if ($row["Location"]) $location = $row["Location"];
        else $location = "Faith Life Church";
        if ($row["City"]) $city = $row["City"];
        else if ($row["Sarasota"]) $city = "Sarasota";
        else $city = "Branson";
        if ($row["State"]) $state = $row["State"];
        else if ($row["Sarasota"]) $state = "FL";
        else $state = "MO";
    }
    if ($location) {
?>
<li><?php echo $location; ?></li>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Am I missing something, here?

JJ

Comment: Don't omit the `{curly braces}` in your conditionals, it makes them hard to read and could very well be the root of your problem here.

Comment: it's seems odd that you are trying to compare strings like they are numbers.  How would you expect it to determine if a string "Music02" is less then a string "Music01"?  You should probably consider comparing actual integers/numbers/etc.

Comment: Use some other comparison.  `stripos` might be an appropriate function here to check for the occurrence of "Music" in `$row['Number']`

Comment: @Dunhamzzz I guess I've just always left `{}` out when it was just one command.  I can see the point of readability, but would it really effect code execution?

Answer (score 2):

When you compare a string in this manner, you essentially are saying any string not equal to `Music01`.  It can get complicated.  See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Get a true integer, and then do your comparison for more predictable results.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong. Initialize your variables first, then override them if needed. This will prevent any oddities where you might lose a case and a variable isn't being defined.

```
$location = "Faith Life Church";
$city = "Sarasota";
/*...*/
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $variable => $value) {
        $variable = strtolower($variable); //Location => location
        $$variable = $value; //$location = $value
    }

}
```

That aside, you're comparing a number with a string. Strip the number out of the string, then compare.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're comparing a string to a string with less than `<`, that will literally return `true` every time. You just need to check for the word 'Music` in the array key right?

```
if (strpos($row["Number"], 'Music') !== false) {

}
```

Comment: I use `if ($row["Number"] && $row["Number"] < "Music01")` for another part of the page and it has worked correctly every time I've tested it.  I wonder what the difference is.

Comment: I assure you it's not working as you intended :) I've done a couple of tests and comparing any string with `<` or `>` will always return true unless one of the values is 0 in which case it will returns false.